# How can I remove startup messages from the Debug Console for C++ in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, configuration

[These are the messages I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjjTk.png).

I know they can be removed by modifying my launch.json configurations. I did that, but it only removed the messages telling me a symbol was loaded; the messages in blue are still present. Below you can see what my launch.json looks like. How do you solve this?

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

       {
        "name": "Debug C++",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "logging":{
            "moduleLoad": false,
            "threadExit": false,
            "processExit": false
        }
        }
    ]
    
}
```

Comment: Please don't post texts in pictures, the text should be posted as a text block.

Comment: see if you can add the `-q` option to the gdb command

Comment: Why do you want to remove the messages? What problem are they causing?

Comment: @rioV8 Sorry, but I am new to programming and do not use the terminal to type in any commands. I simply press Run in the top toolbar of VSCode. So, I do not know how I can add -q since I am not using any commands.

Comment: @Alan Birtles It makes things harder to read; just for convenience.

Comment: VSC is typing these commands for you, gdb has to be started by somebody somehow

Comment: @rioV8 I am confused on how I would add -q though. Would that be done in task.json or launch.json? Or would it be done somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

As for the introductory startup message, you can suppress that by passing [`--quiet`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/gdb-man.html) to GDB. For example, in your launch config, `"miDebuggerArgs": "--quiet",`. Or you could do it through a configuration file as described [here](/a/71476647/11107541).

As for the rest of the messages, I don't know of a way to make them not get printed. You can clear the debug console by right clicking in it and selecting "Clear Console", or you can bind a keyboard shortcut to clear it. Ex. (in keybindings.json, which you can open using the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction",
    "when": "inDebugRepl"
}
```

Comment: Adding `"miDebuggerArgs": "--quiet"` removed the first part of the message, but I am confused why clearing the debug console would help with dealing with the remaining messages.

Comment: @MoonLightWarrior I'm saying you have to do the rest manually and I know how make them not get printed.